# hibernate different types of one-to-one relationships on a single class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to figure out the best way to accomplish a relationship in hibernate. I have a Customer object. Each customer has a technical contact, a billing contact, and a sales contact. Each type of contact has the exact same data structure (phone, email, address, etc).

My first thought was to create a Contact table, and then have three columns in the Customer table - sales_contact, billing_contact, technical_contact. That would make three distinct foreign key one-to-one relationships between the same two tables. However, I have found that this is very difficult to map in Hibernate, at least using annotations.

Another thought was to make it a many to many relationship, and have a type flag in the mapping table. So, any Customer can have multiple Contacts (though no more than three, in this case) and any Contact can belong to multiple Customers. I was not sure how to map that one either, though. Would tere be a type field on the map table? Would this attribute show up on the Contact java model object? Would the Customer model have a Set of Contact objects. or three different individual Contact objects?

So I am really looking for two things here - 1. What is the best way to implement this in the database, and 2. How do I make Hibernate map that using annotations?

Comment: Why did you find it difficult to map ? Surely @JoinColumn would smash this one ?

Comment: Does @JoinColumn work if the column is named something different on the related table? in Customer, the column name would be "sales_contact_id", while in Contact the column name would be "contact_id" - if I annotate with @JoinColumn(name="sales_contact_id") will Hibernate know to map that to "contact_id"?

Comment: for sure, provided that Contact or whatever is its own table it'll know.

Comment: Sure enough - guess I got a bit ahead of myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as :

```
@Entity
public class Contact {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String phome;
    private String email;
    private String address;

    // ... Getters and Setters
}
```

---

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
    private Contact billingContact;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
    private Contact salesContact;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
    private Contact technicalContact;

    public Customer() {
    }

    // ... Getters and Setters
}
```

---

Now, if you want to make the difference between a *BillingContact* and a *SalesContact* at the object level, you can make *Contact* abstract, and implement it with each type of contact. You will have to annotate the parent class with `@Inheritance` to specify the inheritance strategy of your choice (SINGLE_TABLE sounds appropriate here, it will use a technical discriminator column - see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168).

Answer (score 0):

How about using @OneToOne and just naming the @JoinColumn differently for each type:

```
@Entity
public class Contact {
     @Id
     private String id;

     private String phone;
     private String email;
     private String address;

     // ... Getters and Setters
}

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="billingContact_ID")
    private Contact billingContact;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="salesContact_ID")
    private Contact salesContact;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="technicalContact_ID")
    private Contact technicalContact;

    public Customer() {
    }

    // ....
}
```

For each row in Customer table should create three rows in Contact table